# Can you use "him" for a wolf?

Tags: grammaticality, personal-pronouns, animacy

I encountered this:

> This is like dangling a big, juicy steak in front of a wolf, without letting him eat it.

Using "him" for a wolf sounds sort of non-native English, as if the sentence was written by somebody from Eastern Europe or something.

But if you do it this way:

> This is like dangling a big, juicy steak in front of a wolf, without letting it eat it.

... then it looks/sounds stupid with the repeated "it".

A third variant would be:

> This is like dangling a big, juicy steak in front of a wolf, without letting them eat it.

But that also sounds odd to me.

Which is the correct way?

Answer (score -1):

Your question does not give enough context, so I will think of two versions.
***It*** is clearly the grammatically correct way to refer to animals, there is no doubt about that, everybody accepts this as true. BUT, it is so interesting that in fact your second sentence is the one that sounds non-native, not the first one. Non-natives do tend to stick to the rules with the risk of hyper correctness. Natives instinctively avoid repetitions. Therefore,

> ... without letting it eat it.

sounds less native to me.

You haven't mentioned if in the rest of the text you are quoting from, this wolf is also referred to with *he, his, him*. If that is the case, and I hope it is, there is no problem then. If the wolf is the "protagonist" of the narrative (which can be an article about the life of wolves for example), then I don't see why a native cannot refer to the wolf using the personal pronoun. Here is proof [(BBClearningenglish)](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/language/askaboutenglish/2009/01/090120_aae_paula.shtml):

> There are times that someone might use ‘he' or ‘she'. For example, if you watch ***a wildlife show***, it is likely that *the commentator will refer to an animal that is featured in the programme as **he** or **she***. Equally, ***in a work of literature*** the writer might refer to an animal that is a character in the story as ‘he' or ‘she'. The great novel *'Tarka the Otter'* by Henry Williamson is a fine example of this choice of writing style.
>
> - The otter gave but a glance to the bird; ***she*** was using all her senses to find enemies.
>
> So, why do we use ‘she' or ‘he' to refer to animals? Simply, it acts to personalise the animal.

[UsingGrammar](https://www.usinggrammar.com/english-grammar/he-she-it-for-animals.php) explains another possibility that licenses the use of *him* here:

> *It is tolerable to use ‘he’ and ‘she’ **if the sex of the animal is known**.* Such a naming usually applies to ***animals that are typically not pets***. There are often male and female forms for such animal designations:
>
> - Do you see that bull there? ***He*** is my best one.
>
> In this statement, ‘bull’ is male cattle and occasionally referred to with ‘he’.

I doubt that in the rest of the text the author uses *it* to refer to the wolf, and only in your example he chooses "him" to avoid repetition. A native would stick to *it* and reformulate the sentence so as to avoid repetition of two different 'it's.
As for your third sentence, using the *singular them* doesn't help and feels unnatural. I do not see it used for animals and I do not recommend it

Answer (score -3):

## Use the first option. Here's why:

Well, according to the basics of English Grammar, the word, **"it"** should be used for an animal, unless and until it has a close, personal relationship with the concerned person (i.e it is a pet).

Also, I have seen sentences, like "He is a lion" and "She is a lioness". Here, both the animals are obvious strangers to the narrator. And yet, the words "he" and "she" have been used, just to show evidently the gender differences.

So, in your case, if I had been you, I would've gone with the **first option**. Not because the second option is **grammatically incorrect**, but because it (first option) sounds nice. But the third option is definitely incorrect!

Bottom line: YOU CAN OBVIOUSLY USE BOTH (first as well as second).
BUT, IT WILL BE BETTER TO USE THE FIRST OPTION. THE WORD "him" SUITS IN THE SENTENCE. THAT'S IT!

Comment: Calling an animal _him/her_ is not 'non-native English'. We do it if the gender of the animal is obvious (as with Santayan's lion and lioness) or, informally, if we are seeing the animal as a 'personality'.

Comment: Can you provide some proof of your statement, please? A cow can be seen to be female whether you know her or not and, similarly a bull or a cock pheasant can be seen to be male even if you have no other knowledge of him. The only time when I would use 'it' for a mammal, bird or other animal would be when I did not know its gender. There is a good argument for using "it" in the quoted passage but using 'he' merely indicates that the speaker is thinking of a male wolf.

Comment: See [*When to Use Gendered Pronouns for Animals*](https://erinwrightwriting.com/animal-pronouns/), which cites three references.